# Пирамида из чисел

Tags: java

Нужно вывести пирамиду

```
             1
          3     5
       7     9    11
   13    15    17    19
21    23    25    27    29
```

Я думаю её нужно составить с помощью двумерного массива,
но у меня не получается. Буду рад, если кто-то поможет составить код. В приведённом ниже коде я пытался составить пирамиду, но с другими числами вышло всё очень коряво, и в итоге даже пирамиды не получилось

```
int[][] primed = new int[4][];
primed[0] = new int[1];
primed[1] = new int[2];
primed[2] = new int[3];
primed[3] = new int[4];
int k = 0, i, j;
for (i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    for (j = 0; j < i + 1; j++) {
        primed[i][j] = k;
        k++;
    }
for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < i + 1; j++)
        System.out.print(primed[i][j] + "  ");
    System.out.println();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Накидал на коленке:

```
for (int i = 0, c = 5, num = 1; i < c; i++) {
    for (int l = c - i; l > 0; l--) {
        System.out.print(" ");
    }
    for (int l = 0; l <= i; l++) {
        System.out.print(num + " ");
        num+=2;
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Вывод:

```
      1 
     3 5     
    7 9 11    
  13 15 17 19   
 21 23 25 27 29
```

Ну а дальше, всё в ваших силах и фантазии.